# Autofac resolving dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I am really new to autofac and having issues.
I am using Web API and I have set my module up like this:

```
public class CormarModule : Module
{


    // Fields
    private readonly string _connectionStringName;
    private readonly connectionType _connection;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public CormarModule() {
        _connectionStringName =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringName"];
        _connection = _connectionStringName.ToUpper().Contains("LIVE") ? connectionType.Live : connectionType.Test;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {

        // Singletons
        builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>().As<DatabaseContext>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork<DatabaseContext>>().As<IUnitOfWork>().SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(c => new OracleUnitOfWork(_connectionStringName)).As<IOracleUnitOfWork>().SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(c => new AdvancedEncryptionStandardProvider(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rm:key"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rm:secret"])).As<IAdvancedEncryptionStandardProvider>().SingleInstance();

        // Register our services         
        builder.RegisterType<AccountService>().As<IAccountService>();
        builder.RegisterType<DeliveryInformationService>().As<IDeliveryInformationService>();
        builder.RegisterType<EmailService>().As<IEmailService>();
        builder.RegisterType<LogService>().As<ILogService>();
        builder.RegisterType<OrderService>().As<IOrderService>();
        builder.RegisterType<OrderLineService>().As<IOrderLineService>();
        builder.RegisterType<PaymentHistoryService>().As<IPaymentHistoryService>();
        builder.RegisterType<PrincipleProvider>().As<IPrincipleProvider>();
        builder.RegisterType<ProductService>().As<IProductService>();
        builder.RegisterType<RefreshTokenService>().As<IRefreshTokenService>();
        builder.RegisterType<StockService>().As<IStockService>();
        builder.Register(c => new UserStore<User>(c.Resolve<DatabaseContext>())).As<IUserStore<User>>();

        // Single instance
        builder.RegisterType<OAuthProvider>().As<OAuthProvider>();
        builder.RegisterType<LogProvider>().As<ILogProvider>();
        builder.RegisterType<RefreshTokenProvider>().As<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>();
        builder.Register(c => new SendGridProvider(c.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>(), c.Resolve<IEmailService>(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridApiKey"])).As<ISendGridProvider>();
        builder.Register(c => new UserProvider(_connectionStringName, c.Resolve<IUserStore<User>>(), c.Resolve<IAdvancedEncryptionStandardProvider>(), c.Resolve<ISendGridProvider>())).As<IUserProvider>();

        // Per request
        builder.RegisterType<DeliveryInformationProvider>().As<IDeliveryInformationProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<JournalProvider>().As<IJournalProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<StockProvider>().As<IStockProvider>().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies).InstancePerRequest();

        builder.Register(c => new AccountProvider(_connection, c.Resolve<IAccountService>(), c.Resolve<IPrincipleProvider>(), c.Resolve<IAdvancedEncryptionStandardProvider>(), c.Resolve<IPaymentHistoryService>())).As<IAccountProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register(c => new ProductProvider(_connection, c.Resolve<IProductService>())).As<IProductProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register(c => new OrderProvider(_connection, c.Resolve<IOrderService>(), c.Resolve<IPrincipleProvider>(), c.Resolve<IAdvancedEncryptionStandardProvider>())).As<IOrderProvider>().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies).InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register(c => new OrderLineProvider(_connection, c.Resolve<IOrderLineService>(), c.Resolve<IPrincipleProvider>(), c.Resolve<IAdvancedEncryptionStandardProvider>())).As<IOrderLineProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
    }
}
```

I am struggling with the different scopes.
A little background before I explain my issue.

Each **Provider** has a required **Service** and each **Controller** has one or more **Providers** injected.
Each **Provider** could have an optional **Provider** which should only be resolved when a method invokes that provider.

The problem I have is I don't know how to set that up.
I was going to inject the lifetime scope into the constructor and in the method, resolve the required **Provider**, but I have read this is bad practice, plus it would create a new instance. I would like to use one instance per request, but only if it is need in that request.

I hope that makes sense and I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you're doing pretty good.

What you need is to take a dependency on a `Func<Provider>`. When you ask Autofac a `Func<>` it returns a factory method, to be called instead of `.Resolve<Provider>`.

See [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) and [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) for documentation.

You can write it this way:

```
private OptionalProvider _instance;
private Func<OptionalProvider> _providerGetter;

public OptionalProvider Prov
{
    get { return _instance ?? (_instance = _providerGetter()); }
}

public MyProvider(Func<OptionalProvider> getter)
{
    _providerGetter = getter;
}

public void MethodRequiringOptionalProvider()
{
    // just use property Prov and let Autofac handle the rest
}
```

Another suggestion: instead of injecting directly the _connection string parameter, just create a `CormarConfig` class, to be registered with `.RegisterInstance` to store all your configuration options.
This way you just call `RegisterType` and let Autofac resolve all the type parameters (you get rid of those ugly `Resolve` calls).

If all your services inherit from a common ancestor or implement a common interface, you can register them all via [Assembly Scanning](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html) and `AsImplementedInterfaces`. You would get rid of all the clutter in your module.